# SOQL Query with a Subquery that uses GROUP BY and HAVING throws unknown error

Tags: soql

I'm trying to query a list of records from a custom object (SB_User__c) where the value in the Email__c field is not unique.

The following query captures the entire table as expected:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Email__c, External_Id__c
FROM SB_User__c
ORDER BY Email__c, Name
```

And my subquery returns a list of Email__c values that are not unique:

```
SELECT Email__c
FROM SB_User__c
GROUP BY Email__c
HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
```

But when these queries are combined, I receive an unknown error:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Email__c, External_Id__c
FROM SB_User__c
WHERE Email__c IN (
    SELECT Email__c FROM SB_User__c
    GROUP BY Email__c
    HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1)
ORDER BY Email__c, Name
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to without involving apex?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is probably in the having clause, i already run a similar query with this editor online:

[online editor for sql queries](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_orderby3)

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID IN (
SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING CustomerID > 50)
ORDER BY Country ASC, CustomerName DESC;
```

and this query runs just ok, you can check the having clause.